# Fails to start LogMiner with PLS-00306

Tags: sql, oracle11g

When I started LogMiner session with the following statements (in SQL*Plus with role sysdba) as copied from Oracle's tutorial [Using LogMiner to Analyze Redo Log Files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm#i1010243)

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR( -STARTTIME => '14-Nov-2013 01:30:00', -ENDTIME => '14-Nov-2013 23:45:00', -OPTIONS => -DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG + -DBMS_LOGMNR.CONTINUOUS_MINE);
```

I got an error below:

```
BEGIN DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR( -STARTTIME => '14-Nov-2013 01:30:00', -ENDTIME => '14-Nov-2013 23:45:00', -OPTIONS => -DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG + -DBMS_LOGMNR.CONTINUOUS_MINE); END;

  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(14-Nov-2013 01:30:00, 14-Nov-2013 23:45:00, +(-(DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG), -(DBMS_LOGMNR.CONTINUOUS_MINE)))'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I was not sure what I did wrong. I have tried with other combinations such as the ones below but could not succeed:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(-OPTIONS => -DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG);
```

Or

```
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(0,0, '14-Nov-2013 01:30:00', '14-Nov-2013 23:45:00','', -OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG);
```

Anyone knows why this happens and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why there are minuses in front of the arguments, both names and values. I see that they are also in the documentation. Perhaps they are there to show that there is no end of line.

Try this:

```
BEGIN DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(STARTTIME => '14-Nov-2013 01:30:00', ENDTIME => '14-Nov-2013 23:45:00', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG + DBMS_LOGMNR.CONTINUOUS_MINE); END;
```

(which is)

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(
    STARTTIME => '14-Nov-2013 01:30:00',
    ENDTIME => '14-Nov-2013 23:45:00',
    OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG + DBMS_LOGMNR.CONTINUOUS_MINE);
END;
```

I also recommend providing dates using the `TO_DATE` function, as in:

```
TO_DATE('14-Nov-2013 01:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: You're right. Removing the minus sign works :(. Oracle documentation does need to change, sigh.... Thanks a lot

Comment: For me the statement fails because of the `execute` (v12.1) , after change to `begin/end` works. AFAIK the minus signal is only to avoid the break line inside of the parameter at execute syntax.